# Dictionaries store pairs. Who stores triples?

Tags: python, dictionary, store

We would use a dictionary to store for example:

```
a={"breakfast":"banana","lunch":"fish","dinner":"soup"}
```

What would your approach be if you want to add the time attribute alongside every key-value set. Of course not:

```
a={"8AM":"breakfast":"banana","2PM":"lunch":"fish","8PM":"dinner":"soup"}
```

Then I would like to use one or more keys to access a value.

Maybe by doing a trick with lists?

Comment: how many keys can you use to access a value? Show an example of that

Comment: Use a dictionary where value is of type tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to use a dictionary and possibly lists, I would recommend determining what your "primary key" is and creating a nested structure like this:

```
a = {
    'breakfast': {
        'time': "8AM",
        'items': ['banana', 'yogurt']
    },
    'lunch': {
        'time': '2PM',
        'items': ['fish', 'tartar sauce']
    },
    'dinner': {
        'time': '8PM',
        'items': ['soup', 'salad']
    }
}
```

The time for each meal is variable, but we all know we eat breakfast, lunch, and dinner (or at least we should). Doing this you can then determine the time and items that were consumed:

```
a['breakfast']['time']
'8AM'

a['breakfast']['items']
['banana', 'yogurt']
```

Comment: yeah, I would agree but the question references dictionaries and lists explicitly

Answer (score 5):

You can use a tuple as a dictionary key:

```
a = {("8AM", "breakfast"): "banana",
     ("2PM", "lunch"): "fish",
     ("8PM", "dinner"): "soup",
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a dictionary with a tuple as the key:

```
>>> a={("8AM","breakfast"):"banana",("2PM","lunch"):"fish",("8PM","dinner"):"soup"}
>>> a["8AM","breakfast"]
'banana'
```

Or if you want to look up the time and the food using just the meal name:

```
>>> a={"breakfast":("8AM","banana"),"lunch":("2PM","fish"),"dinner":("8PM","soup")}
>>> a["breakfast"]
('8AM', 'banana')
```

Comment: In that case you have to write the whole tuple. What if we want to access the value using only "breakfast" and not "8AM"'

Comment: See my edit, moved the tuple to the value instead of the key.

Comment: @UneUne that's why you were asked about keys

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {"8AM":{"breakfast":"banana"},"2PM":{"lunch":"fish"},"8PM":{"dinner":"soup"}}
```

Using:

```
>>>a['8AM']['breakfast']
'banana'
```

Other:

```
def r(_d,_target):
    result = []
    for k, v in _d.items():
        if(k == _target):
            if type(v) == type({}):
                for x in v.keys():
                    result.append(v[x])
            else:
                result.append(v)
        if type(v) == type({}):
            r2 = r(v,_target)
            if len(r2) > 0:
                for l in r2:
                    result.append(l)
    return result

>>> r(a,"breakfast")
['banana']
>>> r(a,"8AM")
['banana']
>>> r(a,"dinner")
['soup']
```